# arXiv submissions no longer process after switch to TeX Live 2020

Tags: natbib, texlive, arxiv, subfig, texlive-2020

After the switch to TeX Live 2020, arXiv's automated TeX processing fails to process my source and throws a bunch of warnings. The warnings and errors are:

- From package natbib, all my citations are undefined.
- References to labeled sections in the document are undefined.
- Emergency stop due to an undefined control sequence:

  ```
   <argument> \caption@lfmt
   {\@nameuse {sub\@captype name}}{\@nameuse {thesub\@...
   l.58 }
  ```

I suspect the undefined control sequence is associated with the subfig package, because of the signature and because it occurs at the first figure.

I tested this using a previous submission that arXiv processed correctly before the switch to TeX Live 2020 and arXiv fails to process it.

**EDIT:** All the submissions also compile correctly on Overleaf and locally when using TeX Live 2020.

**EDIT:** The `\sidesubfloat` command from the subfig package is very likely the cause of the automated processing failure. Still unable to figure out why, or solve the citation and reference issues.

Comment: you will have to prepare a small document that we can try and check if it works with a texlive 2020.

Comment: Here is a link to a test document that uses the packages that I suspect are causing the issues: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pj2o4h2x9n8cvn4/AADpHGc3Q0QAn_E3dHAatpZqa?dl=0

Comment: looks as if the floatrow package didn't adapt to newer caption versions.

Comment: Would that make the compilation fail on arXiv but not locally or on Overleaf?

Comment: It fails for me in texlive 2020, I didn't check with an older system.

Comment: That's interesting. What platform are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by including the files caption.sty and caption3.sty from the caption package in the submission. These files seem to be different in the Mac distribution of TeX Live 2020, which is the version that worked for me. They can be found in texlive/2020/texmf-dist/text/latex/caption

Comment: This worked for me after a few hours of struggling, thank you.

Comment: This also worked for me, but I just fetched current copies of caption.sty and caption3.sty from https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/